# The translation between percentage data and decimal data

Tags: r

I have a data and there is a percentage column but when I input this dataframe the percentage column was changed into  character type and became decimals.

And there are NAs in this column so I don't know how to translate them to percentage type.

Or I also wanna the numeric type.

Here is my sample data:

```
file.f <- structure(list(drug = c("DrugA    ", "DrugB1", "DrugB2", "DrugB3", 
"DrugC1", "DrugC2", "DrugC3", "DrugC4", "DrugA  ", "DrugB1", 
"DrugB2", "DrugB3", "DrugC1", "DrugC2", "DrugC3", "DrugC4"), 
    type = c("P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", 
    "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", "P_resistant ", 
    "P_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", 
    "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", "G_resistant ", 
    "G_resistant "), value = c(18, 430, 156, 0, 60, 66, 113, 
    250, 16, 425, 154, 0, 56, 64, 111, 248), group = c(0.8751, 
    0.9885, 0.9871, NA, 0.932, 0.969, 0.982, 0.99, 0.8751, 0.9885, 
    0.9871, NA, 0.932, 0.969, 0.982, 0.99), class = c("Class A ", 
    "Class B", "Class B", "Class B", " Class C", " Class C", 
    " Class C", " Class C", "Class A ", "Class B", "Class B", 
    "Class B", " Class C", " Class C", " Class C", " Class C"
    ), drug_order = c(4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 
    6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I suppose you should get rid of NA values because the common data type for numbers and characters is character type

Comment: Yeah,I get that and I have finished it. You can see the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that first defines a `num2perc` function to take care of the conversion.

The function has 3 arguments:

1. `x` the vector to be converted to percentage;
2. `digits` the number of decimal digits of the result, see the argument of the same name in [round](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html). The default is `digits = 0`
3. `fill` the value to substitute for `NA` values. The default is `fill = NA`, meaning not to remove missing values.

Then the function can be applied directly to a numeric column or used in a `dplyr` pipe.

**The function**

```
num2perc <- function(x, digits = 0, fill = NA){
  na <- is.na(x)
  y <- round(100*x, digits = digits)
  y[na] <- fill
  if(is.na(fill))
    y[!na] <- paste0(y[!na], "%")
  else
    y <- paste0(y, "%")
  y
}
```

---

**Base R usage**

```
num2perc(file.f$group)
num2perc(file.f$group, digits = 2)
num2perc(file.f$group, fill = 0)
```

---

**`dplyr` pipe example usage.**

```
library(dplyr)

file.f %>%
  mutate(percent = num2perc(group))
```

### Contributed package solution.

Package `scales` has functions to format numbers as percentages.

```
scales::percent(file.f$group)
scales::percent(file.f$group, accuracy = 1)

file.f %>%
  mutate(percent = scales::percent(group, accuracy = 1))
```

Comment: I have a question about data that was originally percentage but changed when I entered it. If there is a method I can use to ensure that the original data does not alter during input, please let me know.

Comment: @花落思量错 If you have another question you should ask it as a separate question. Please post what are the input instructions and what is the expected output.

Comment: Ok,I get it.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
```

If you do not want to have decimals, just round by 2 if you want to have decimals round by 3.

```
file.f.2 <- file.f %>% 
  mutate(file.group = paste0(round(as.numeric(group), 2)*100,"%"))
file.f.2
        drug         type value  group    class drug_order file.group
1  DrugA     P_resistant     18 0.8751 Class A           4        88%
2     DrugB1 P_resistant    430 0.9885  Class B          1        99%
3     DrugB2 P_resistant    156 0.9871  Class B          2        99%
4     DrugB3 P_resistant      0     NA  Class B          3        NA%
5     DrugC1 P_resistant     60 0.9320  Class C          5        93%
6     DrugC2 P_resistant     66 0.9690  Class C          6        97%
7     DrugC3 P_resistant    113 0.9820  Class C          7        98%
8     DrugC4 P_resistant    250 0.9900  Class C          8        99%
9    DrugA   G_resistant     16 0.8751 Class A           4        88%
10    DrugB1 G_resistant    425 0.9885  Class B          1        99%
11    DrugB2 G_resistant    154 0.9871  Class B          2        99%
12    DrugB3 G_resistant      0     NA  Class B          3        NA%
13    DrugC1 G_resistant     56 0.9320  Class C          5        93%
14    DrugC2 G_resistant     64 0.9690  Class C          6        97%
15    DrugC3 G_resistant    111 0.9820  Class C          7        98%
16    DrugC4 G_resistant    248 0.9900  Class C          8        99%
```

Note: I rounded by 2 there are no decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought out a good method:

```
file.f_g<-as.data.frame(file.f$group)
file.f_g
file.f3<-data.frame(lapply(file.f_g, function(x) 
  ifelse(is.na(x),{NA},paste0(round(as.numeric(x),3)*100,"%"))
  ))
file.f3
```

Answer (score 0):

I also find another better solution:

```
#####  official  formattable package
install.packages("formattable")
library(formattable)
percent(rnorm(10, 0, 0.1))
percent(rnorm(10, 0, 0.1), digits = 0)
percent("0.5%")
percent(c("15.5%", "25.12%", "73.5"))
## output:
> percent(rnorm(10, 0, 0.1))
 [1] -12.78% 16.25%  4.99%   2.83%   -4.06%  21.86%  17.28%  22.42%  9.36%   11.56% 
> percent(rnorm(10, 0, 0.1), digits = 0)
 [1] 7%  -3% 3%  7%  13% -4% 7%  -0% -7% 6% 
> percent("0.5%")
[1] 0.5%
> percent(c("15.5%", "25.12%", "73.5"))
[1] 15.50%   25.12%   7350.00%

##
percent(file.f$group)
 [1] 87.51% 98.85% 98.71%  NA    93.20% 96.90% 98.20% 99.00% 87.51% 98.85% 98.71%  NA    93.20%
[14] 96.90% 98.20% 99.00%
```